# What type of uniform and cap emblem could my great grandfather be wearing? We have been told that it is maybe a Cossack

Tags: russia, identification, uniform

This picture was given to me and I was told it was the only picture we have of our great grandfather. He looks quite young in the photo (maybe around 15-16, he was born about 1878). My guess is this was taken around 1895-1900. We have no real papers on when he came to the US except on his census that states he arrived around 1900. It only states he was from ‘Russia’. We would love to find more about him, as he abandoned his wife and 8 children in 1924 and there was never a trace of him after that.

[image]

Comment: This might be tough because Russia didn't have a "standard" uniform in the 1900's. It's a potential that he is wearing either the Calvary Officer  or a guards infantry officer I did find one video though that at 3:16 shows an illustration that resembles the picture
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=esNyj5Qkl3U

Comment: That uniform really doesn't look like what a Cossack would wear; it's more of an enlisted soldier's uniform. But I'm no expert.

Comment: This doesn't look like a typical Russian uniform. The military cap form is different as well as the lack of the typical imperial [cockade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockade#Cockades_of_the_European_military) on the cap. Also no shoulder badges.

Comment: The cap looks *vaguely* like a form of a **konfederatka** (predecessor of the polish [Rogatywka - Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogatywka)) military cap.